# Button In java to click once do one thing, and when clicked after that do another thing

Tags: java, if-statement, applet, awt

I have a button and I want it to do something when its pressed once, and something when its pressed after that. I tried putting the `if(e.getSource)` command once, then after the same command but It just adds a label then it instantly removes it. I want it to add the label after its clicked, then when its clicked again remove it. Give me an example and ill figure it out.

*please...*

Comment: Have you tried setting a variable once the button is clicked for the first time? Or changing the text of the button and checking on Click which text is on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a flag to the relevant class:

`boolean isClicked = false;`

And in your listener, check to see if isClicked is true or false. If false, do whatever you want to do after the initial click and set the flag to true. If true, do whatever you want to do after subsequent clicks.

```
void onActionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    if(!isClicked){
         isClicked = true;
         //do work for first click
    }
    else {
         //add label, do other work for clicks after first
    }
```

Comment: `if(!isClicked){...}else{...}`

Comment: @sanbhat I'm aware that that looks better, and if the asker knows this as well then he'll write it that way. If he doesn't, though, then this will be much clearer to him. (he seems fairly new to java)

Comment: @NaameNameee Seeing that you're fairly new here, just a heads up: If my answer helped you, please feel free to accept it and/or upvote it

Comment: and yes i am new i got this applet i made with help of everyone: http://pastebin.com/AukYdUVV

Comment: some of the data there is useless

Comment: i was trying to make a password but it doesnt seem to work :P and thanks

Comment: @NaameNameee Not quite sure what you're talking about. If you have a new problem, please explain it in a new question and I'll help you with it there